# firebase child values as string in array to populate a picker swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, string, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do you use Firebase values that have been placed into an array to poplulate a picker.  This is the code I'm using to add values to an array and print them:

```
let dbRef1 = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Live Scoring Male")

    dbRef1.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        let data = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
        let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.compArray.append(name)
        print("\(name)")

    })
```

However the array values aren't being loaded into the picker when I call:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
        return compArray[row]
    }
}
```

This code works if I hard code the string in the array but not if I try to load the values from Firebase.

Comment: should use `snaphsot.child("name") as? String` , that syntax isn't valid anymore

Comment: You need to tell compiler type of `snapshot.value` so try like this way. `if let dic = snapshot.value as? [String:Any], let name = dic["name"] as? String { self.compArray.append(name) }`

Comment: @NiravD Ok great thanks, now I can't seem to get this into the picker though. I can print the snapshot values but they aren't loading into the picker. How should it be different from a normal hard coded string array where you just use something like this...func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? { if (pickerView.tag == 1) { return compArray[row] }}

Comment: @user7371866 Edit your question with what you are currently trying.

Comment: @NiravD Thanks for your responses, I've updated the title and question

Comment: @user7371866 Are you having multiple pickerView?

Comment: @NiravD yes there are 4 pickers which is why the tag is present, I deleted the other 3 because I can hard code those.  For tag == 1 I need to pull the values from Firebase, I just confirmed this picker has a tag of 1 in the main.storyboard

Comment: @user7371866 Is this will printing `print("\(name)")` name properly? When you add new child.

Comment: @NiravD yes when I add a new name it prints the new one and all previous names

Comment: @user7371866 Reply here that my solution is works for you or not?

Comment: @NiravD That makes a lot of sense to reload the picker components, I'm getting the error "ambiguous reference to member uipickerview title for row component" though

Comment: @user7371866 Don't get your above comment can you edit your question and where you are getting error, if possible also show the screenshot of error.

Comment: @NiravD my mistake, I had to replace "pickerView" with "CompPicker" since it was the title of that picker's outlet.  Thank you so much! I appreciate your help and persistence.

Comment: @user7371866 Welcome mate, Glad it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reload the `pickerView` components to change it with new dataSource array.

```
let dbRef1 = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Live Scoring Male")

dbRef1.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

    if let dic = snapshot.value as? [String:Any], let name = dic["name"] as? String { 
        self.compArray.append(name) 
        print("\(name)")

        //Reload the pickerView components
        self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()

        //Or you can reload the pickerView's specific component
        self.pickerView.reloadComponent(0)
    }
})
```

Comment: This is correct.  For the next user, please note to make sure "pickerView" before reloadAllComponents is the same as your picker's outlet.  Thanks Nirav!

Comment: @user7371866 Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to convert the snapshot to a dictionary and then access the name from the dictionary:

```
let data = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
self.compArray.append(name)
```

Comment: This is working properly to add the values to the array in a manner that they can be printed but I can't get them to show up inside the picker? Does this have to happen before viewDidLoad? I have the snapshot code in viewDidLoad then a later picker func... func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? { if (pickerView.tag == 1) { return compArray[row] } }